# accessing values of Async method called inside constructor in ngOnInit()- Angular 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to angular.There is a situation where I do not know what to do next.Every suggestion and solution will be welcomed.

```
  constructor() {
       this.getCustomers();
  }
```

this.getCustomers() method that will assign value to customers variable.

```
  async getCustomers() {
    let response = await this.customerService.get();
    this.customers = response.data;
  }
```

get() returns a promise with array of customer Array[6]

```
 ngOnInit() {

console.log(this.customers) // undefined

 }
```

here  this.customers is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and most recommended way to work with async functions in Angular is using Observables. Lemme show you.

First of all you have the service where you make the HTTP request to the backend of the application. ( I assume that you're already familiar with the services so let's just explain the function)

```
public get() {
   // This is the get method of your customer service
   return this._http.get("http://your-backend/customers");
}
```

You should provide the Http service to work with it and the above method will return an Observable. Now you're ready to catch the response from your component. Component:

```
public customers: Customer[]; 

constructor( private customerService: CustomerService ) {
   // It's not a good practice to call here to your customer service so just define the variable where you'll store the data
   this.customers = [];
}

ngOnInit() {
    // Now here is where you call to get the data
    this.customerService.get()
      .subscribe( res => {
         this.customers = res;
         console.log(this.customers); // Here you will have the customers
      });
    
    console.log(this.customers); // Here the array is empty
}
```

Comment: You meant `this.customerService.get().subscribe( ... )` I guess.

Comment: Yeap, I wrote it fast and didn't notice

Comment: thank you for  your suggestion, but what if i want  values here =>   console.log(this.customers); // Here the array is empty

Comment: This is against the async programming itself. It's like calling a console.log() inside a setTimeout and after that calling again another console.log() but without setTimeout and pretend to print the setTimeout's console.log first. When the console.log which is outside the subscribe is called the array is still empty cuz the observable response haven't arrived yet